# Has anything changed with /dev/urandom on MacOS Monterey?

Tags: bash, macos, random, macos-monterey

I used to be able to generate a random character sequence from `/dev/urandom` using the following line:

```
cat /dev/urandom | LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=' | fold -w 100 | head -n 1 | grep -i '[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?=]' | tr '[a-m][n-z][A-M][N-Z]' '[n-z][a-m][N-Z][A-M]'
```

but this no longer functions after I upgraded to Monterey. The output I receive is nothing more than `Input error`. Has something changed with this OS version? How can I now generate a sequence of 100 random characters from `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: The `tr` command isn't removing control characters for some reason, so `fold` is having trouble parsing its input (I assume it's trying to read it as UTF-8).

Comment: you can add `LC_COLLATE=C` or use `GNU tr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Monterey, `locale` shows `LANG` as set, and the grand override value, `LC_ALL` as unset, as it is typically set elsewhere for example https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/utf8-98/index.html
To make this work in Monterey, just change the language or the override to the POSIX standard default:

`LANG=C`
or
`LC_ALL=C`

In Monterey, the character type locale could be set to:
`LC_CTYPE=en.US.UTF-8`
to avoid angle-bracket-enclosed escape codes which sneak through given that LANG is set now.